# Trying to figure out block data

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm trying to write a python driver for RFID-230-2 card reader.
As the document says, in order to communicate with the device, one has to make a packet in the format below:

```
|STX|ADDR|LEN|CMD/STU|DATA|BCC|

STX:  Communication start character, 1 byte, 0x02  
ADDR: Device Addr, 1 byte, 0 can be used in any addr  
LEN:  Data length, 1 byte, data length of CMD/STU+DATA
CMD/STU: Command byte (Host->Reader) or Status byte (Reader->Host), 1byte   
DATA: Data information, byte is not specified. Can be not existed   
BCC:  Section checking character, 1 byte, the XOR value of all the bytes except STX, BCC
```

In order to be able to read data from rfid reader, on has to set `CMD` to `0x38` and set the `DATA` as follows:
[image]

but I haven't been able to figure out how to create such data format.
any Help will be appreciated. This is what I have gone so far

```
STX = 0x02
REQUEST_FORMAT = 'bbbbbb'

def communicate(self, command, data):
    address = 0x0
    length = 1 + len(str(data)) + len(str(command))
    bcc = address ^ length ^ command
    i = struct.pack(REQUEST_FORMAT, STX, address, length, command, data, bcc)
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
    ser.write(i)
    time.sleep(.1)
    resp = ser.read()
```

The program stop at `resp = ser.read()` waiting for a resp.
This is the full doc if anyone is intrested.
http://www.tetagroup.net/products/pdf/rft230.pdf

################ EDIT 1

as the document says, in order to read a card you have to provide `Request Card Parameter` + `Card Series No.`
you can get the card series no from Anti Collide command return data. but the question is, how can I put that card series no along side request card paramteres to select the card?
the card series no is 4byte data. I tried this but

`communicate(0x33, [0x93, 1487824920])`

```
File "main.py", line 21, in communicate
i = struct.pack('BBBB%sBB' % len(data), STX, address, length, command, *(data + [bcc]))
struct.error: ubyte format requires 0 <= number <= 255
```

1487824920 is the result of:

```
a = binascii.hexlify(data)
card_series = int(a, 16)
```

Comment: `"\x0A"` ? how to detect line/packet end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your approach. Firstly the BCC computation should include the data bytes. Secondly, data bytes depend on which command is being used, so if there are not any present, for example with the get version command, the format needs to be modified. I suggest your first command should be to get the version number. This will help you to prove that it is working correctly:

```
import binascii        
import struct

STX = 0x02

def as_bytes(number):
    output = []

    while number:
        output.insert(0, number % 256)
        number >>= 8

    return output

def communicate(command, data=[]):
    address = 0x0
    length = 1 + len(data) 
    bcc = address ^ length ^ command

    for b in data:
        bcc ^= b

    if len(data):
        i = struct.pack('BBBB{}BB'.format(len(data)), STX, address, length, command, *(data + [bcc]))
    else:
        i = struct.pack('BBBBB'.format(len(data)), STX, address, length, command, bcc)

    # Display the command to be sent in hex 
    print binascii.b2a_hex(i)

    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
    ser.write(i)
    time.sleep(.1)
    resp = ser.read()        
    print binascii.b2a_hex(resp)  # display response

communicate(0x21)           # Get version number
communicate(0x23, [0])      # Set baud rate of device to 9600
communicate(0x33, [0x93] + as_bytes(1487824920))
```

To pass more data bytes, add more numbers to the list.

Comment: I have added an `as_bytes()` function to convert an integer into a list of bytes which should hopefully do what you need.